# How can I get the number of div inside a div in scrapy with css?

Tags: scrapy, css-selectors, web-crawler

I would like to count the number of div (so 2) inside the div "thumb-container".

[image: code to extract]

So far I have used css selectors so I would like to keep using css and not xpath:

```
yield {
            'date':datetime.date.today(),
            'title': response.css('h1::text').extract()[-1],
            'rating':response.css('bl-rating::attr(rating)').get(),
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getall()](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.SelectorList.getall) returns a list so you can get it's length.

With the code you provided (next time post it as text and not as image):

```py
In [1]: len(response.css('div.thumb-container div').getall())
Out[1]: 2
```